# Can anyone explain this code from "codebat"?

Tags: python-3.x

I was solving some beginner problem at **"codebat"**. Then I came up with this problem. I couldn't solve this so I viewed the solution. They showed me this.
Can anyone explain the code?

**Problem**:Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative.

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if negative:
    return (a < 0 and b <0)
  else:
    return((a < 0 and b >0) or (a > 0 and b < 0))
```

Comment: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Conditions

Comment: What specifically about it are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if negative` checks whether `negative` is true or false:

- If `negative` is true, then the function returns the result of `(a < 0 and b <0)`, which is true if and only if both values are negative.
- If `negative` is false, then the function returns the result of `(a < 0 and b >0) or (a > 0 and b < 0)`, which is true if one is negative and the other positive.

Comment: Thanks for helping.